# building SQL Query From another Query in php

Tags: php, sql, build

When I Try to  built  Query from another Query in php code I Faced some problem
can you tell me why? :(

code :

```
$First="SELECT ro.RoomID,
               ro.RoomName,
               ro.RoomLogo,
               jr.RoomID,
               jr.MemberID,
               ro.RoomDescription 
          FROM joinroom jr,rooms ro 
         where (ro.RoomID = jr.RoomID)
           AND jr.MemberID = '1' ";

$sql1 = mysql_query($First);

$constract .= "ro.RoomName LIKE '%$search_each%'";
$constract="SELECT * FROM $sql1 WHERE $constract ";// This statment is Make error
```

thanks ,Query it is Work now ! ..

But I Faced another problem ,When I Display the Result of this Query ..

code :

```
$run =mysql_query ($sql);

while($runrows=mysql_fetch_assoc($run))         
{
  $RoomName=$runrows["ro.RoomName"];
  $RoomDescription=$runrows["ro.RoomDescription"];

  echo "<center><b>$RoomName</b><br>$RoomDescription<br></center>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the last part of the error, which you are facing, you need to remove the prefix "ro." from the right hand parts of the assignment statements.

So your actual code should have been:-

```
$run = mysql_query ($sql);
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    $RoomName = $runrows["RoomName"];
    $RoomDescription = $runrows["RoomDescription"];

    echo "$RoomName $RoomDescription";
}
```

Try this one above, & you should be working fine; until & unless there is some error regarding your field's existence in your database table or your database connection.

Comment: Thank ! 
it's Working well now!  : )

Comment: Thanks to you, for testing it quick enough & setting it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery to add the LIKE-part:

```
SELECT ro.RoomID,ro.RoomName,ro.RoomLogo,jr.RoomID, jr.MemberID,ro.RoomDescription
FROM joinroom jr, rooms ro 
WHERE ro.RoomID = jr.RoomID
  AND jr.MemberID = '1'
  AND ro.RoomName LIKE '%$search_each%'
```

Btw, make sure to sanitize/escape the `$search_each` variable.